# Verify signature of PKCS#7 signed file using Python

Tags: python, linux, openssl, pkcs#7

On Linux, I need to verify the signature of a PKCS#7 signed file and retrieve its original contents using Python and its standard libraries.

Currently, I can verify the contents of this file (and retrieve its actual contents) using OpenSSL terminal utility as follows:

```
openssl smime -verify -in myfile.xml -inform DER -noverify
```

I have received this command from a friend. I don't really understand the options and directives. Is there any way to do this with Python without using any 3rd party libraries?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious but why is your file called myfile.xml if it's DER encoded?

Comment: Well, the name isn't real. It's just an example. Actually, part of the problem is that I don't understand a thing about the entire signing/verification process.

I don't know what signing a file does or what it's used for or why there are so many techniques/algorithms.

Comment: Do you consider OpenSSL a third party library? You can use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to call `openssl` on the command line, write custom [C wrappers](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/) for the OpenSSL library or use [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) to call directly into the OpenSSL shared object library. It's also possible to access fields in the DER encoded object using an ASN.1 parsing package like [`pyasn1`](http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/), but you'll have to find/implement your own copies of the signature verification algorithms.

Comment: A decent explanation of the steps in the signature verification process (although not written in python) can be found [here](http://qistoph.blogspot.com/2012/01/manual-verify-pkcs7-signed-data-with.html)